# Horizontal space between \items in a list with pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate

Im trying to get something like the picture but Im not able to get the rectangle to the next line and have a horizontal space between the items

[image]

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item eigth  \addtocounter{enumi}{1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline=(current bounding box.north west),
        level/.style={sibling distance=10mm/#1},scale =0.5
      ]

      \draw [draw=black] (2,4) rectangle (0,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \item 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        baseline=(current bounding box.north),
        level/.style={sibling distance=10mm/#1},scale =0.5
      ]

      \draw [draw=black] (2,4) rectangle (0,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need a hammersledge like tikz for that?

Answer (score 2):

Just make the text a node the baseline of which you make the baseline of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
      \node(X) {eigth};

      \draw [draw=black,path picture={
      \draw (path picture bounding box.south) -- 
      (path picture bounding box.north);
      }] ([yshift=-1ex]X.south west) rectangle ++ (2,-4);

    \end{tikzpicture}\addtocounter{enumi}{1}

    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
      \node(X) {eleven};

      \draw [draw=black,path picture={
      \draw (path picture bounding box.south) -- 
      (path picture bounding box.north);
      }] ([yshift=-1ex]X.south west) rectangle ++ (2,-4);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This does not introduce horizontal spacing between the items, but you can add such spacing e.g. by adding `\path ([xshift=2em]current bounding box.east);` to the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: It could be easier to add the horizontal spacing using ``enumitem``'s ``itemjoin`` key in the options of the ``enumerate`` environment.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks! Yes, this is a good point. I was meaning to say that this does not introduce unwanted additional spacing but you are right, the `enumitem` methods are more appropriate to obtain consistent spacing.

Comment: @JoesphMama It is the `,path picture={
      \draw (path picture bounding box.south) -- 
      (path picture bounding box.north);
      }`. This is a trick that adds a vertical line in the middle, which will be in the middle even when you change the dimensions of the rectangle.

Comment: what if i wanted to add more lines

Comment: @JoesphMama Then you may need a different construction. It depends on which lines (horizontal, vertical, whatever), equally spaced or not, and so on. This post was written to produce something along the lines of the screen shot you posted.

Comment: Could you tell me how I could get the rectangle cut into thirds

Comment: @JoesphMama One example: add `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to the preamble and use `\draw [draw=black,path picture={
      \draw foreach \X in {1,2}{($(path picture bounding
   box.south west)!\X/3!(path picture bounding box.south east)$) -- 
      ($(path picture bounding
   box.north west)!\X/3!(path picture bounding box.north east)$)};
      }] ([yshift=-1ex]X.south west) rectangle ++ (2,-4);`. There are zillions of possibilities, and if one proposes one typically many additional answers pop up suggesting the poster of the first option was unaware of all the other options.... ;-)